# Different pretty formats for git log and git show?

Tags: git, git-log

I have this in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[format]
    pretty = %C(yellow)%h%Cred%d%Creset - %C(cyan)%an %Creset: %s %Cgreen(%cr)
```

This makes the output of `git log` look like this (plus some nice colors):

```
6b1d043 (origin/master) - Ismail Badawi : Don't redirect to index after saving query. (28 hours ago)
df98a3e - Ismail Badawi : Store example queries in database & cache results (30 hours ago)
6de44ab - Ismail Badawi : Add sanity check tests for different pages. (31 hours ago)
7b6b46b - Ismail Badawi : Save query results for saved queries. (31 hours ago)
```

I find this format easy to scan through. I don't like that it also affects `git show` though; in particular, I'd like to be able to see the full commit message in the output of `git show`, not just the title line; also the actual date instead of relative, the author email, etc.

Is there some way to use different default formats for `git log` and `git show`?

Comment: Any reason why not use [aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both git `log` and `show` use the same configuration.

```
--format=<format>
    Pretty-print the contents
    ...
    Note: you can specify the default pretty format in the repository configuration (see git-config(1)).
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html

However, why don't you just define an alias to one of them and use that instead? For example, you could have `git alias.vshow 'show --pretty=<your other format string>'`.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having both `show` and `vshow` with the understanding that `show` is never what I want and `vshow` is always what I want. It just feels wrong -- intuitively what I'm doing is altering the behavior of `show`, not introducing a new command. (By contrast, I have various aliases that add flags to `diff`, but I still use the bare `diff` in some cases). If git allowed you to define aliases that shadow commands, then I would do that.

Comment: You are right, overriding commands isn't possible, that's just how the processing loop in git is coded, internal commands are looked up before aliases. But similarly this is just how pretty formatting is defined, it is shared between `log` and `show`.

Comment: Another similar solution is to use Bash- (or another shell-) alias instead of Git alias. But I agree with @Ismail Badawi, it feels wrong and it would be better to specify different formats for `log` and `show` in the git config.